# Having trouble with Insert Sort for Linked List. Only prints first value of list when I try to sort the list in ascending order

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, singly-linked-list, insertion-sort

I am writing a program for one of my classes and am stuck on the section that asks
to sort a linked list in ascending order. I have tried to sort the list but when
I run the function it only prints the first value. I know the print function works
because I can run it without Insert Sort and it prints fine.

My code is as follows:

```
#include "linkedList.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void swap(struct Link *first, struct Link *second){
  struct Link* temp = first;
  temp->next = first->next;
  temp->value = first->value;
  first = second;
  first->next = second->next;
  first->value = second->value;
  second = temp;
  second->next = temp->next;
  second->value = temp->value;
}

struct Link* listInsertionSort(struct Link* head) {

  /*
   * This function should perform an insertion sort on the list whose head is
   * provided as the function's argument, so that the values in the list are
   * sorted in ascending order, starting at the head.
   *
   * The sort should be done without allocating any new Link structs or any
   * other auxiliary data structures.
   *
   * Return a pointer to the new head of the list.
   */

struct Link* cur = head;
cur->next = head->next;
struct Link* count;
for(;cur->next != NULL; cur = cur->next){
  for(count = cur->next; count != NULL; count = count->next){
      if(cur->value < count->value){
        swap(cur, count);
      }
  }
}


return cur;

}
```

And the linkedList.h file is here:

```
#ifndef __LINKEDLIST_H
#define __LINKEDLIST_H

#define TYPE int

/* Single link structure */
struct Link {
  TYPE value;
  struct Link* next;
};

struct Link* listInsertionSort(struct Link* head);
struct Link* reverseList(struct Link* head);
struct Link* reverseListRecursive(struct Link* head);

#endif
```

And the test file is here (Although there shouldn't be any error here
since this was provided to all students in the class by our instructor):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>

#include "linkedList.h"

struct Link* buildLink(int n, int rev, int mod) {
  struct Link* head = (struct Link*)malloc(sizeof(struct Link));
  struct Link* cur = head;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (rev)
      cur->value = n - i - 1; //If rev is 1, creates list from high value to low value
    else
      cur->value = i; //If rev is 0, creates list from low value to high value

    if (mod)
      cur->value = cur->value % mod; //Modifies list so that it increments up to value of mod

    if (i + 1 < n)
      cur->next = (struct Link*)malloc(sizeof(struct Link)); //Creates next link in the array
    else
      cur->next  = 0; //If less than the cap it sets next character to NULL, ending the list
    cur = cur->next; //Sets current link to next link to continue for loop
  }

  return head;
}

void printLL(struct Link* l,char* s) {
  printf("LL %s: ",s);
  while (l != 0) {
    printf("%d ", l->value);
    l = l->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main() {
  // We aren't practicing good memory management
  //    here....
  struct Link* l = buildLink(10, 0, 4);
  struct Link* r = listInsertionSort(l);
  printLL(r, "Sort 0-9 mod 4"); //This should print 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 3 3

}
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is here? The error is somewhere in listInsertionSort(struct Link* head) but I have tried multiple different combinations with no success.

The current output is : LL Sort 0-9 mod 4: 1
When it should be: LL Sort 0-9 mod 4: 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 3 3

Comment: I don't think your swap function will work, I don't see how it could. Please read up on pointers

Comment: `struct Link* temp = first; temp->next = first->next; temp->value = first->value;` What do you think this does given that temp = first?

Comment: `temp->next = first->next;` This is like a = a as temp = first

Comment: when you assign a pointer to a pointer, they point to the same "object".

Comment: Test your swap() implementation; it's broken (generally a swap needs to make a complete temporary copy of one of the entities; you just make copies of pointers to them).

Comment: BTW, since this linked list is not doubly linked, you'll need to pass pointers to the nodes preceding each one of the nodes you wanna swap to the swap function too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the problem I was having.

Instead of returning cur, I was supposed to return head. I also changed the swap function so that it did not include swapping values of the links in the list because that was unnecessary and looked messy.